# Is there any way to represent an array of arbitrary length with a required number of members in TypeScript, like `minOccurs` in XSD?

Tags: xml, typescript, types, abstract-syntax-tree

## TL;DR

Is there a way to represent an array of arbitrary size with one or more required elements in Typescript? This expresses what I want, but this is not possible when written like this

```js
type BookMetadata = [...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[], Publisher, ...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[]]
```

## Problem

I want to write types that can accurately represent XML elements in JSON format (specifically the [unist](https://github.com/syntax-tree/unist) format).

One problem I ran into is that TypeScript arrays or tuples don't accurately represent how child elements behave in XML. Specifically, I want to represent the `minOccurs` attribute in some way.

Say we have an XSD defining an element like (this is a truncated version of [the CrossRef XML schema](https://data.crossref.org/schemas/crossref5.3.1.xsd))

```xml
<xsd:element name="book_metadata">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="contributors" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element ref="titles"/>
                <xsd:element ref="publisher" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I want to write types for the `unist` representation of this (leaving out attributes), which looks like

```js
const bookMetadata: BookMetdata = { 
  type: "element"
  name: "book_metadata"
  attributes: {}
  children: [
    {
      type: "element",
      name: "contributors",
      children: ...
    },
    { 
      type: "element",
      name: "titles",
      children: ...,
    },
    { 
      type: "element",
      name: "publisher",
      children: ...
    }
  ]
}
```

When typing this, I run into some problems with TSs array/tuple types. The most obvious way to type `BookMetadata` would be

```js
type BookMetadata = (Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[]
```

But this misses that `Publisher` needs to occur at least once.

The closest I can get is

```js
type BookMetadata = [Publisher, ...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[]] | [...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[], Publisher]
```

But this misses some configurations like `[Contributors, Publisher, Titles, Publisher]`.

Ideally I would want to do

```js
type BookMetadata = [...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[], Publisher, ...(Contributors | Titles | Publisher)[]]
```

but typescript does not allow multiple rest operators on unbounded arrays in a tuple.

Does anyone know any workaround for this? Is it even possible?

## Alternatives?

If it's not possible, what's best practice here? Just type it as an array and try to use typeguards in the library?

Comment: A friend of mine wrote a xml-parser for ts but im not sure if this is helping you [link](https://github.com/Pawl-Patrol/type-level-stuff/blob/main/xml-parser/input.ts)

Comment: This is a case of "overdoing" types. You don't *need* to convey that Publisher needs to appear at least once in the types. You just need to know that it does (document it in some way if needed). It *is* possible to make something like this work, but it's similar to a type guard function anyways.

Comment: Sorry man, not possible.

The closes you can get is
`type E = Contributors | Titles | Publisher; type BookMetadata = [Publisher, ...E[]] | [E, Publisher, ...E[]] | [E, E, Publisher, ...E[]]`
But this might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Filly Your fiend's type is useless. It's not even a template literal string type. It's just a hardcoded string. I'd say that is another case of, as @kelly puts it, "overdoing" types. He would be better off just putting `export type Input = string`